# auto delete file in selenium 4 grid when browser close failed

Tags: selenium-grid

as the https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/11702 statement,add following command
options.AddArgument("--base-dir-downloads");
options.AddArgument("--enable-manage-downloads");
when the browser closed, the download file was still there
and I also see the node log as follows:

09:24:55.010 WARN [LocalNode.lambda$new$5] - Removing Downloads folder associated with e2ff169af2e66707569ca394414d417c

09:24:55.011 WARN [LocalNode.lambda$new$6] - Removing Uploads folder associated with e2ff169af2e66707569ca394414d417c

expect the download file in the current session auto-delete